# Abbreviate an expression to an identifier

Tags: c++

Is there a way to abbreviate an expression in C++? For instance, if i had something like this

```
ui.myplot->graph(0)
```

and I would like to abbreviate it as `mygraph`, so that instead of going like this

```
int a =   ui.myplot->graph(0)->val;
```

I could do this

```
int a = mygraph->val;
```

I know typedef wont work here. Any suggestions ?

Comment: Is there some reason you can't use `#define` ?

Comment: `auto &mygraph = ui.myplot->graph(0);` (or `decltype` if you want to be more generic about `const`) seems like the likely only logical solution.

Comment: @librik: avoid define as much as possible. It's not type-strong and it can give all kinds of unexpected syntax issues.

Comment: With "abbreviate an expression", do you mean that the expression is still evaluated whenever you use the abbreviation. I.e. if you abbreviate `rand()` as `R`, do you expect a new value every time you use R ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a reference:

```
const auto& mygraph = ui.myplot->graph(0);
```

Or a mutable reference if you need to alter the value:

```
auto& mygraph = ui.myplot->graph(0);
```

References are designed to be used as *aliases*; the fact that this most often comes up in parameter passing is somewhat misleading. They can just as well be used locally to alias the results of complex expressions, such as deeply nested fields of an object.

Comment: Use `auto&&` instead of `const auto&` or `auto&`. Otherwise you change the constness.

Comment: @nosid: I was under the impression that `auto& x = y;` deduces `x` as `int&` if `y` is non-`const` and as `const int&` if `y` is `const`. That is, `auto` deduction has essentially the same rules as for template parameters.

Comment: The latter is correct, the former is not. If `y` is a temporary, you can't bind it to a non-const lvalue-reference.

Comment: @nosid: Oh, that’s true. But what does that have to do with changing constness?

Comment: @JonPurdy: because `ui.myplot->graph(0)` looks very much like a function call which results in a temporary, so you're forced to use the `const` version?

Comment: @KillianDS: Sure, but the compiler will tell you as much. I would still prefer `const auto&` because `auto&&` can silently give you a mutable variable when you didn’t want one.

Comment: My error. I was under the impression, `auto&` will be deduced to `const Type&` if used with an rvalue. However, that happens only if used with a const lvalue reference.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're using Qt with Designer and UI files, since the code you're showing uses Qt paradigms.

Put a `Graph* mygraph` member in your class, and set it to point to your graph(0):

```
MyClass {
  Q_OBJECT
public:
  Graph* mygraph;
  MyClass();
}
```

In the constructor, after the `ui->setupUI(this)`:

```
MyClass::MyClass()
{
  ui->setupUi(this);
  mygraph = ui.myplot->graph(0);
}
```

Now you can use it in your class methods.

```
int MyClass::getValue()
{
  int a = mygraph->val();
  return a;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't hesitate to define local variables. They are very convenient to improve readability, and they will be optimized away by the compiler (reference or actual variable), if not compiled with -O0 (in this last case, I'm not sure of the optimisation behaviour)

```
int a =   ui.myplot->graph(0)->val;
```

becomes

```
auto& myParticularGraph = ui.myplot->graph(0);
int a =   myParticularGraph->val;
```

Now `myParticularGraph` is like an "alias" for `ui.myplot->graph(0)`

Comment: This likely won't work, `graph(0)` is a function call and will return a temporary (rvalue), which you can't bind to an `auto&`